# How to read the all files in a directory and display them using cat command?

Tags: command-line, filemanager, cat

I have a directory `employer/`. In this there are 5 `.txt` files.

I want to combine the data from all 5 files and show into the command prompt using `cat` or create another file and save the result in that file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First go to `employer/` directory (using `cd /path/to/employer/` command), then use one of the following commands:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt file5.txt
```

or, simple:

```
cat *.txt
```

If you want to save the output in a new file, then you can use:

```
cat *.txt >new_file.txt
```

If you want both, to write the output to standard output and to a new file, then you can use:

```
cat *.txt | tee new_file.txt
```

Comment: what is the usage of tee

Comment: I can not abstain to say this: please RTFM [`man tee`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee).

Comment: @navee: `tee` writes its input to standard output and to a new file